# Session-file-store not getting all the data from MSAL

Tags: node.js, msal.js

Lately I've been expanding on a Microsoft example [MS Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal) to write a web app using MSAL authentication. Works just fine. Normal auth flow seems to be: sign-in => acquire-token. But it got annoying having to log in every time node restarted. So I started using session-file-store.

And this works... sometimes. Most of the times it complains as soon as I request a token.

On investigating I found that after I sign in (not using session-file-store) a tokenCache, account and such is stored in the session. After which I can request a token. Most of the time when I activate session-file-store the tokenCache and such is not written to the session. In which case a request for a token results in an error: "no_account_in_silent_request".

in the acquireToken code there is a piece of code responsible for throwing the error I guess

```
const tokenResponse = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent({
     account: req.session.account,
     scopes: options.scopes || [],
});
```

since the session does not include an account section this fails I guess. But I don't have a clue as to why that information is not there when using session-file-store but is there without it.

I saw that to use session-file-store you have to extend express-session. Like this:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);
```

and I made my app use it as follows

```
var fileStoreOptions = {};
app.use(session({
    store: new FileStore(fileStoreOptions),
    secret: process.env.EXPRESS_SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false, // set this to true on production
        //expires: 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 hour
    }
}));
```

as in an example I found.

Did review the options I could use to resolve the issue, but none seem to apply.

What am I doing wrong?

PS:
Found a thread somewhere with a similar problem. There was talk it could have something to do with the host platform. I'm working on Windows. But tested just now on Ubuntu. Same problem.

PPS:
Made a switch to "better-sqlite2-session-store" to avoid the problem. Makes it a bit harder to see what is stored, but at least it (seems to) works